# distorted depthmap when calibrating stereo cameras

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration, depth

I have two identical cameras with identical manual fixed focus lenses, and i've been trying to calibrate them so my depthmap looks good. However the main issue I have is that the "floor" in the depthmap becomes angled and distorted as seen from the epilines. I've been trying many code samples online and I still get these distortions.

I have taken about 91 images both from the left camera and right camera. I 3d printed a case so they are as parallel as possible.

I slid my checkerboard (18x24") around the frame and rotated it slightly but I only moved it around on my garage floor.

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you
I used the code as described in this tutorial: https://python.plainenglish.io/the-depth-i-stereo-calibration-and-rectification-24da7b0fb1e0
to generate the stereoMap.xml database and used this database to rectify my images before trying to generate the depthmap

Here are my results:

calibration: [image]

epilines:[image]

test image:[image]

depthmap:[image]

Edit: inserted the images instead of links

Comment: Although you have given link for tutorial code, as per stackoverflow guidelines it will be better if you could paste your exact code (with images) here to help others minimize their time investment to reproduce what you have done till now.

Comment: @Abhi25t No worries I figured it out. I just had to bring the checkerboard pattern closer to the camera where the checkerboard would fill in 75% of the frame